# JQuery do not add leading zeros to values

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery code (fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/jts4sr9b/5/)

I have used `toFixed(2)` to set the values to 2 decimal places

when checking / unchecking the box its showing leading zeros. how can i stop this?

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/jts4sr9b/6/

Comment: try testing the fiddle - its not working

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse total result into float and then use toFixed(2), like

```
$("#total_allocated").val(parseFloat(parseFloat($("#total_allocated").val()) + outstanding).toFixed(2));
```

instead of

```
$("#total_allocated").val(parseFloat($("#total_allocated").val()) + outstanding);
```

apply same for all results.

Comment: add this into the fiddle and test it. it doesnt work correctly

Comment: Its working for "Total Allocated", are you looking for "Outstanding"? you must have to update same for that..

Comment: every time you check/uncheck the box its adding values to the Total Allocated box

Comment: check this updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jts4sr9b/13/ its working exactly how i want it to but i need the decimal to be to 2 decimal places on all values

Comment: so use .toFixed(2) for all values.

Answer (score 0):

What about using regex for this in JS? Try tinkering around with different regex expressions to get exactly what you are looking for.

```
var regexp = /^\d+\.\d{0,2}$/;
```